# Building a new array from multiple arrays with nested foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I'm stuck and confused on how I can create a new array from these 3 arrays and then pass the values from the new array to a function to insert the values into a Database.

**The 3 Arrays:**

```
flavourname Array ( 
    [0] => Red Sour Cherry Extract 
    [1] => Red Energy (Red Bull) 
)
flavourcompanyname Array ( 
    [0] => Amoretti 
    [1] => Bolsjehuset 
)
flavourpercent Array ( 
    [0] => 5 
    [1] => 2 
)
```

**Expected result:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [flavourname] => Red Sour Cherry Extract 
        [flavourpercent] => 5 
        [flavourcompany] => Amoretti  
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [flavourname] => Red Energy (Red Bull) 
        [flavourpercent] => 2 
        [flavourcompany] => Bolsjehuset 
    )
)
```

**The Code I've tried that is the closest:**

```
foreach($flavourname as $key => $value) {

    foreach($flavourpercent as $key2 => $value2) {

        foreach($flavourcompanyname as $key3 => $value3) {
            $newarray[] = array(
                'flavourname' => $value, 
                'flavourpercent' => $value2,
                'flavourcompany' => $value3
            );
        }
    }
}


print_r($newarray);
```

**OUTPUT from print_r():**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [flavourname] => Red Sour Cherry Extract 
        [flavourpercent] => 5 
        [flavourcompany] => Amoretti
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [flavourname] => Red Sour Cherry Extract 
        [flavourpercent] => 5 
        [flavourcompany] => Bolsjehuset 
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [flavourname] => Red Sour Cherry Extract 
        [flavourpercent] => 2 
        [flavourcompany] => Amoretti 
    )
    [3] => Array ( 
        [flavourname] => Red Sour Cherry Extract 
        [flavourpercent] => 2 
        [flavourcompany] => Bolsjehuset 
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [flavourname] => Red Energy (Red Bull) 
        [flavourpercent] => 5 
        [flavourcompany] => Amoretti
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [flavourname] => Red Energy (Red Bull)
        [flavourpercent] => 5
        [flavourcompany] => Bolsjehuset
    )
    [6] => Array (
        [flavourname] => Red Energy (Red Bull)
        [flavourpercent] => 2
        [flavourcompany] => Amoretti
    )
    [7] => Array (
        [flavourname] => Red Energy (Red Bull)
        [flavourpercent] => 2
        [flavourcompany] => Bolsjehuset
    )
)
```

*As you can see the above array is not what I want at all.*

**Then I want to pass the values of the new array to this function to insert into the DB:**

```
foreach($newarray as $new) {
    $this->addRecipeFlavours($lastID, trim($new['flavourname']), trim($new['flavourcompany']), $new['flavourpercent'], $usereid);
}
```

**The Function:**

```
/**
    ADD FLAVOURS
*/

public function addRecipeFlavours($recipeID, $recipeFlavourName, $recipeFlavourCompanyName, $recipePercent, $usereid) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO recipe_flavours (recipe_flavour_name, recipe_flavour_company_name, recipe_flavour_percent, recipe_flavour_recipe_id, recipe_flavour_ueid) VALUES (:recipeflavourname, :recipeflavourcompanyname, :recipeflavourpercent, :recipeflavourid, :usereid)'; 
    $stmt = $this->queryIt($query);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':recipeflavourname',$recipeFlavourName);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':recipeflavourcompanyname',$recipeFlavourCompanyName);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':recipeflavourpercent',$recipePercent);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':recipeflavourid',$recipeID);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':usereid',$usereid);
    if($this->execute()) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

instead of `nested for loop` use other two array key

```
<?php
$flavourname = array ( "Red Sour Cherry Extract",  "Red Energy (Red Bull)" );
$flavourcompanyname = array ( "Amoretti", "Bolsjehuset" );
$flavourpercent = array ( 5 , 2 );
echo "<pre>";
foreach($flavourname as $key => $value) {
    $newarray[] = array('flavourname' => $value, 'flavourpercent' => $flavourpercent[$key], 'flavourcompany' => $flavourcompanyname[$key]);
}
print_r($newarray);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [flavourname] => Red Sour Cherry Extract
            [flavourpercent] => 5
            [flavourcompany] => Amoretti
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [flavourname] => Red Energy (Red Bull)
            [flavourpercent] => 2
            [flavourcompany] => Bolsjehuset
        )

)
```

Comment: Apart from these being the wrong way around, `'flavourpercent' => $flavourcompanyname[$key], 'flavourcompany' => $flavourpercent[$key]` this works great, thank you very much, how could I test if flavourcompany is empty and assign a value?

Comment: what you say i cant understand `how could I test if flavourcompany is empty and assign a value?`

Comment: @CodeX use the isset function to see if it is set to a value

Comment: I tried `foreach($newarray as $new) {$flavourcompany1 = trim($new['flavourcompany']);
     if($flavourcompany1 == '') {
      $flavourcompany1 == 'User Defined';
     }}` but no joy..

Comment: try this `$flavourcompany1=!empty($flavourcompany1')?$flavourcompany1: 'User Defined';` turnory operator @CodeX

Comment: Perfect, its all working exactly how I want it to, thankyou all for your help, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_map` to loop thru the arrays.

```
$flavourname = //Your array
$flavourcompanyname = //Your array
$flavourpercent = //Your array

$result = array_map(function($a, $b, $c){
    return array(
        'flavourname' => $a,
        'flavourcompany' => $b,
        'flavourpercent' => $c,
    );
}, $flavourname, $flavourcompanyname, $flavourpercent);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [flavourname] => Red Sour Cherry Extract
            [flavourcompany] => Amoretti
            [flavourpercent] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [flavourname] => Red Energy (Red Bull)
            [flavourcompany] => Bolsjehuset
            [flavourpercent] => 2
        )

)
```

Doc: [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: Your loop is wrong , it will take duplicate values .

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate values? This output of the code is the same with the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use one single loop and traverse through each array at once?

```
$mixed = array();
foreach($flavourname as $i => $name){
   $mixed[]=array(
       'flavourname' => $name,
       'flavourcompany' => $flavourcompanyname[$i],
       'flavourpercent' => $flavourpercent[$i]
   );
}
```